How to Convert Hexadecimal Text Fields to Readable Text in ibd2sql Output?
I’m using ibd2sql to recover data from MySQL InnoDB .ibd files. While extracting the data, I noticed that some of the text fields are being output as hexadecimal values like:
0x53205265736f6c76696e67204572726f728180

These fields are originally human-readable text (e.g., TEXT, LONGTEXT), but they are showing up as hex in the resulting SQL dump.
My questions:

How can I ensure that text fields are extracted as readable text rather than hexadecimal?
Could this be an encoding issue (e.g., UTF-8 vs. Latin1)? If so, how can I handle or specify the encoding properly with ibd2sql?
Are there any tools or methods available to convert these hex values back to their original text representation?

UPDATE:
I used -D for debug and get following error in conversion:
[2024-10-20 12:45:49] [DEBUG] BLOB ERROR 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 15: invalid start byte

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!
